# pdb file is not created usi custom wizard to create visual studio 2010 solution

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, wizard

```
i have written the custom wizard which can create visual studio solution and project in it.
Everything is working fine exept one thing.
I Can't see .pdb file in anywhere in my solution because of which i can't debug my project code. how can i get pdb file?
note: after creation of solution, i didnt see Debug folder for solution in my solution directory. but Debug folder for project is there.

following is my code

function OnFinish(selProj, selObj) {
    // debugger;
    try {

        var strProjectName = wizard.FindSymbol('PROJECT_NAME');
        var strProjectPath = wizard.FindSymbol('PROJECT_PATH');
        var strSolutionPath = strProjectPath.substr(0, strProjectPath.length - strProjectName.length);

        strProjectName = wizard.FindSymbol('TARGET_BOX');
        strProjectPath = strSolutionPath + strProjectName;


        selProj = CreateCustomProject(strProjectName, strProjectPath);
        selProj.Object.Keyword = "Toolset";
        SetupFilters(selProj);
        AddConfig(selProj, wizard.FindSymbol('TARGET_BOX'));


        AddFilters(selProj, strProjectPath, strProjectName);

        var InfFile = CreateCustomInfFile();
        AddFilesToCustomProj(selProj, wizard.FindSymbol('TARGET_BOX'), strProjectPath, InfFile);
        PchSettings(selProj);
        InfFile.Delete();

        selProj.Object.Save();
    }
    catch (e) {
        if (e.description.length != 0) {
            SetErrorInfo(e);
        }
        return e.number
    }
}

function CreateCustomProject(strProjectName, strProjectPath) {
    try {
        var strProjTemplatePath = wizard.FindSymbol('PROJECT_TEMPLATE_PATH');
        var strProjTemplate = '';
        strProjTemplate = strProjTemplatePath + '\\default.vcxproj';

        var Solution = dte.Solution;
        var strSolutionName = "";
        if (wizard.FindSymbol("CLOSE_SOLUTION")) {
            Solution.Close();
            strSolutionName = wizard.FindSymbol("VS_SOLUTION_NAME");
            if (strSolutionName.length) {
                var strSolutionPath = strProjectPath.substr(0, strProjectPath.length - strProjectName.length);
                Solution.Create(strSolutionPath, strSolutionName);
            }
        }

        var strProjectNameWithExt = '';
        var strName = wizard.FindSymbol("TARGET_BOX");
        strProjectNameWithExt = strName + '.vcxproj';

        var oTarget = wizard.FindSymbol("TARGET");
        var prj;
        if (wizard.FindSymbol("WIZARD_TYPE") == vsWizardAddSubProject)  // vsWizardAddSubProject
        {
            var prjItem = oTarget.AddFromTemplate(strProjTemplate, strProjectNameWithExt);
            prj = prjItem.SubProject;
        }
        else {
            prj = oTarget.AddFromTemplate(strProjTemplate, strProjectPath, strProjectNameWithExt);
        }
        var fxtarget = wizard.FindSymbol("TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION");
        if (fxtarget != null && fxtarget != "") {
            fxtarget = fxtarget.split('.', 2);
            if (fxtarget.length == 2)
                prj.Object.TargetFrameworkVersion = parseInt(fxtarget[0]) * 0x10000 + parseInt(fxtarget[1])
        }
        return prj;
    }
    catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the PDB file generate on compilation? See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yash/archive/2007/10/12/pdb-files-what-are-they-and-how-to-generate-them.aspx

Comment: Thanks, i am able to solve it. link was useful.